# How to Spatially Join Polygon IDs to Points in R

Tags: r, spatial-join

I am trying to assign a region ID to each record within a point shapefile. Each point would be assigned the Region ID of the region it falls within. The point feature is called "deciles" and the region/polygon feature is "regions".  I keep getting this error:

Error in UseMethod("inner_join") : 
  no applicable method for 'inner_join' applied to an object of class "c('SpatialPointsDataFrame', 'SpatialPoints', 'Spatial')"

```
require(rgdal)
library(dplyr)
library(sf)
deciles<- readOGR("C:\\filepath", "deciles")
regions<- readOGR("C:\\filepath", "regions") 
#Assign each bsu to a region with a spatial join
bsu_regions_join <- inner_join(deciles, regions, by = region_ID)
```

I've also tried these variants and I still get the same error:

```
bsu_regions_join <- st_join(deciles, left = FALSE, regions["region_ID"])
bsu_regions_join <- st_join(deciles, left = FALSE, regions) 
bsu_regions_join <- st_join(regions, deciles, left = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 3):

You are reading your files in with rgdal. Read them in with sf (`st_read`) then you can apply an sf operation like `st_join` to it. Or change your objects from Spatial Point/Polygons dataframe to sf objects using `st_as_sf(deciles)` and `st_as_sf(regions)` and then apply `st_join` to it.

Comment: Thank you so much!  Worked like a charm!